# Unsure how to use List Comprehension on a loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've never used List Comprehensions but have spent the last few hours trying to apply what I've read to a method I'm working on. It's difficult for me to apply the examples I've seen to my case.

Given a list, create a new list of equal size. In that new list, shift all the numbers to the left with zeroes to the right. So for example, [0, 3, 0, 4] will return [3, 4, 0, 0]. I have a working method that does this:

```
def merge(self, line):
    results = [0] * len(line)
    count = 0
    for number in line:
        if number != 0:
            results[count] = number
            count += 1
    return results
```

Each time I try my hand at compressing that, I get stumped by how to accomplish `results[count] = number` without an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
def merge(self, line):
    return ([x for x in line if x] + ([0] * len(line)))[:len(line)]
```

This gets the non-zero items from `line` then pads with zeros, slicing to ensure appropriate length.

As you aren't using any class or instance parameters, this could be made a static method to  remove the unnecessary argument:

```
@staticmethod
def merge(line):
    return ([x for x in line if x] + ([0] * len(line)))[:len(line)]
```

However, note that your current version is clear, readable and more memory-efficient than this (which builds two lists, adds them to make a third then slices out a fourth).

Comment: This method is within a class. I'm unfamiliar with static methods or decorations. I don't quite grasp `[x for x in line if x]`. Shouldn't it be instead `[ x for x in l if x != 0]`?

Comment: @VinBreau `0` evaluates `False` in a Boolean context (and non-zero evaluates `True`), so you don't need `!= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
l = [0, 3, 0, 4]
nl = [ x for x in l if x != 0]
print nl.extend([0] * (len(l) - len(nl))
```

Comment: Your comment combined with that of jonrsharpe above made it click. Fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
def merge(self, line):
    return [item for item in line if item != 0]+[0 for item in line if item == 0]
```

Which runs as:

```
>>> merge([0, 3, 0, 4])
[3, 4, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, just sort the list by boolean key:

```
def merge(self, line):
    return sorted(line, key=lambda x: not bool(x))
```

Yes, this solution contains no list comprehension. But not every problem is solved with a hammer.

Comment: This is neat, but relies on `sorted` being stable (CPython's timsort is, but I'd count that as an implementation detail).

Comment: I'm specifically trying to grasp list comprehensions today. Thanks for showing me something new I wasn't aware of though.

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but here it is in one comprehension:

```
l1 = [0, 3, 0, 4]
l2 = [i for i in filter(bool, l1) + list(repeat(0, len(l1) - len(filter(bool, l1))))]
print l2  # prints '[3, 4, 0, 0]'
```

You might as well not even include the comprehension because it's redundant:

```
l1 = [0, 3, 0, 4]
l2 = filter(bool, l1) + list(repeat(0, len(l1) - len(filter(bool, l1))))
print l2  # prints '[3, 4, 0, 0]'
```

Furthermore, you should probably use some kind of state for the calculation to avoid duplicating work:

```
l1 = [0, 3, 0, 4]
l2 = filter(bool, l1)
l3 = l2 + list(repeat(0, len(l1) - len(l2)))
print l3  # prints '[3, 4, 0, 0]'
```